# no file name in javascript drag and drop

Tags: javascript

iI have this code to create a list of dropped files

```
var list = $("#filedrop ul");
var dt = event.dataTransfer || (event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.dataTransfer);
var files = event.target.files || (dt && dt.files);
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var text = e.target.result;
        var li = new $("<li class=\"list-group-item\">" + e.name + "</li>");
        var del = new $("<span><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></i></span>");
        li.append(del);
        li.attr("data-text", btoa(text));
        list.append(li);
    }
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

The problem is that e.name is undefined, as is if I try to use file.name or files[i].name.

Anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Could you provide your code in a snippet, either here, JS Fiddle, Codepen etc? The event does not have a property called name, so it will be undefined. Are you trying to get the file name to display there?

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the file name, i tried files[i].name, file.name and e.name, all came back undefined. https://jsfiddle.net/psib3r/0ztcetqw/

Comment: I recommend you use a library for what you're trying to achieve, such as dropzone JS (http://www.dropzonejs.com/). Your drop events dataTransfer seems to return no files for me when I test it in Chrome on your JS Fiddle

Comment: OK, so weirdly, i tried again to use file.name instead of e.name and it is now working.